# ul li tag is repeating in view page source using php

Tags: php, html, css

I am fetching menu from database and it displaying proper but when I checked on view page source it displaying like below code:

```
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul>
        <li>About us</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul>
        <li>Contact us</li>
    </ul>
</div> 

etc..
```

It should be display like this below code

```
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About us</li>
        <li>Contactus</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my php code:

```
if (isset($result->num_rows) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <div class="menu-header">
            <ul>
                <li><?php echo $row['Menu_name'];?></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: so take away the `<ul>` from the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put only `<li>` line inside `while` loop like this:

```
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul>
        <?php if (isset($result->num_rows) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                <li><?php echo $row['Menu_name'];?></li>
            <?php }
        } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's right...I forgot about the loop..Thanks for help Mr.d.coder.Its working

Comment: Hey
@d.coder why the if(isset($result->num_rows) ? 
I would think the while loop already does this?
while it can fetch an associative array loop through, so it seems redundant to have the if statement? please correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

code should be

```
if (isset($result->num_rows) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
?>
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul>
<?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  ?>


    <li><?php echo $row['Menu_name'];?></li>

<?php
      }
?>
    </ul>
</div> 

<?php
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

take away `div` and `ul` outside the loop

```
if (isset($result->num_rows) > 0) { ?>
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul>
    <?php // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $row['Menu_name'];?></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div> 
<?php }
```

Comment: Your code has error as you are closing PHP at wrong place after `if` clause. Improve your code and formatting as well...